# How to load cells in scrolling TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView and 1000 cells.

I'm trying to load TableView quickly.

How can I load 25 first cell and then load cells in scrolling TableView ?

Comment: The tableview already works like that. It will only create the visible cells (and a bit more), it will not create cells for the whole array of objects at once. // But maybe you're actually not talking about your tableview but about loading data in a paginated way before populating your array?

Comment: Do you mean a paging mechanism?

Comment: @alireza, Have you got solution?

Comment: I want my tableview load cells by loading like this:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stableviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by Eric in his comment above, tableView/collectionView is very much optimized in its own. TableView/CollectionView loads only the cells that are in the visible index path range and then reuses the same cell. That is why you have

`tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: )` method in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Having all that, I believe you are looking for a way to load the data in chunks rather than loading whole set of data in one shot (like Facebooks home feed, overtime you scroll down to reach the end of tableView it loads few more posts)

If thats your requirement, thats called Pagination. This needs the support from both server and client end.

Make sure you decide the optimal number of data(json object) each response will contain and ask your web API developer to implement pagination logic.

Finally at iOS, implement,

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)

        let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
        let scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
        let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

        if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
        {
            //reached the end of scroll, download next set of data and update your data source
            self.fetchNextSetOfData()
            return
        }
    }
```

You might have to send the server information like offset from which to fetch data from and number of data you are expecting as your web API param

Answer (score -1):

Eric's answer is correct. However if you really want to load 25 first cell and load next cells after that, you have to 
calculate cell height with something like this

**cell height =  Screen height/number of cells to show** 
cell height will vary if you have navigation controller.